# Pass in hard coded params into named Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am creating some hard coded routes that will likely be changed again freely in the future. To abstract the ideas a bit:

We have a controller/method `BuySubscriptionController@start`:

```
class BuySubscriptionController
    function start()
    {
        $plan = Plan::findBySlug($request->get('plan'));

        return view('someView', ['plan' => $plan]);
    }
}
```

We currently have the following route:

```
Route::get('/buy-subscription/start', 'BuySubscriptionController@start');
```

This means the sales team would need to advertise the following urls:

```
site.com/buy-subscription/start?plan=plan-one
site.com/buy-subscription/start?plan=plan-two
```

Now we have been requested to have a few specialized routes:

```
site.com/purchase/the-basic-plan (plan-one)
site.com/purchase/the-mega-plan (plan-two)
```

Now I am trying to add these specialized urls to my routes.  I was hoping to do something as follows, but does not work:

```
Route::get('/purchase/the-basic-plan', [
   'uses' => 'BuySubscriptionController@start', 
   'with' => ['plan' => 'plan-one']
]);

Route::get('/purchase/the-mega-plan', [
   'uses' => 'BuySubscriptionController@start', 
   'with' => ['plan' => 'plan-two']
]);
```

Is there any way to achieve this, simply, without over engineering some new translation layer?  Keep in mind that next week the url might be `/buy/the-god-plan` meaning `plan-one`, so being able to simple add a line to my routes seems ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a route that takes the plan as a parameter, and use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) so that parameter can only take certain values that you allow. So your route definition can look like this:

```
Route::get('/purchase/{plan}', 'BuySubscriptionController@start')
     ->name('purchase-plan')
     ->where('plan', 'the-basic-plan|the-mega-plan');
```

Then in your controller action just use the parameter:

```
class BuySubscriptionController
{
    protected $plans = [
        'the-basic-plan' => 'plan-one',
        'the-mega-plan'  => 'plan-two'
    ];

    function start($plan)
    {
        // You can use an associative array to convert the $plan parameter
        // into the value you need for querying the database
        $plan = Plan::findBySlug($this->plans[$plan]);

        return view('someView', ['plan' => $plan]);
    }
}
```

If you need to generate URLs for the route you can just use the `route` helper method and pass it the plan name:

```
route('purchase-plan', 'the-basic-plan');
```

And you'll get:

```
site.com/purchase/the-basic-plan
```

This solution allows you to add any number of plan names by just adding the public plan for the URL in the `where` constraint of the route, then associating that value with the one you need for the query in your controller's `$plans` property.

Comment: I really like this approach. Simple enough! Thank you.